# VS2010 fails to refresh editor view - looks blurred

Tags: windows-7, fonts, visual-studio-2010, ide

I recently started having problems with the Visual Studio 2010 ide not refreshing editor views when they get focus. When I switch from one editor tab to another, the text in the new tab looks a bit blurred. It refreshes parts of it when I move around, and "select all" makes everything refresh and look nice and sharp again.

I suspect a recent update from Microsoft Update, but I don't know how to find the right one and don't want to revert them all to test.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

The computer is newly built with the new 5:th generation Intel Core i7 5775C with its integrated graphics chip. OS is Windows 7 64 bit with all updates from MS installed for both OS and VS (and everything else).

Screen dump:
[image]

After "select all" it looks sharp again:
[image]

Comment: I found that the problem goes away if I disable hardware graphics acceleration in the options: uncheck Tools --> Options --> Environment --> General --> Use hardware graphics acceleration if available. OK, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is down to bad display drivers designed not to meet expectations of Visual Studio team completely in terms of hardware acceleration.

Read more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/09/16/vs2010-performance-and-bad-video-drivers-hardware-redux.aspx

I have worked on display drivers myself and it is not the most trivial task to perform considering the limited API that Windows exposes. If you want to read about device drivers in general, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver